# How to silence a particular "pointless comparison of unsigned with zero" warning?

Tags: c, warnings

Suppose I have a function like the following:

```
#define LOWER_BOUND 0
#define UPPER_BOUND 42

int is_value_in_range( some_typedef val)
{
    return ((LOWER_BOUND <= val) && (val <= UPPER_BOUND));
}
```

Assuming that I have warnings configured appropriately, if `some_typedef` turns out to be an unsigned type I'll get a warning that there's a pointless comparison of an unsigned type with 0. Of course that's true, and it makes sense.

However, lets say that I *do* want the check against zero to be in the code for one or more possible reasons, such as:

- While the bounds will always be compile time constants, they might be something that could change (and the macros might not 'live' very close to the function). For example, the bounds might be set by passing in options to the compiler.
- I might like to defend against a later change of the typedef to a signed type, since it's possible that each and every use of the typedef might not be closely examined when it's changed.

Is there a decent, reasonably portable way to silence the warning here without turning it off completely?

Something that relies on a 'STATIC_ASSERT()'-like functionality (which is available to me) would be acceptable if it's reasonable. I'm OK with breaking the compile if the type changes to force someone to look at the code.  But it might be important to note that `typeof` isn't something I have available in all the compilers I'm targeting.

I'm specifically looking for C language solutions, so templates aren't any use here...

Comment: If you are open to compiler-specific methods, then you should probably specify your compiler (or compilers)...

Comment: Compiler-specific doesn't sound compatible with "reasonably portable".

Comment: I am looking for 'reasonably portable', but I should have specified compilers anyway, since I might be able to adapt something that works 'well enough' using the preprocessor:  IAR, MSVC and GCC are what I'm interested in.

Comment: I can't make my compiler (gcc 4.2) produce a warning for the given code.  What's the compiler flag?

Comment: @JeremyP: to get the warning with GCC you need `-Wextra` (and maybe `-Wall`, but I think `-Wextra` alone is enough); for MSVC you need `/W4 /Wall`.  I think it's a default with IAR.

Comment: @Michael Burr: I have `-Wall` already.  `-Wextra` does indeed trip the warning.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>If `some_typedef` is not known to be unsigned or signed, I think you're pretty much out of luck.</strike>

If you know in advance that `some_typedef` is unsigned, you could just use

```
#if LOWER_BOUND > 0
    return ((LOWER_BOUND <= val) && (val <= UPPER_BOUND));
#else
    return ((val <= UPPER_BOUND));
#endif
```

Or in this case, you could use my preferred version:

```
    return (val-LOWER_BOUND <= UPPER_BOUND-LOWER_BOUND);
```

**Edit:** I'm going to assume if `some_typedef` is not known to be of particular signedness, then `UPPER_BOUND` and `LOWER_BOUND` must both be positive. Otherwise you would have very wacky results from `some_typedef` getting promoted to unsigned. Thus, you could always safely use:

```
    return ((uintmax_t)val-LOWER_BOUND <= UPPER_BOUND-LOWER_BOUND);
```

Comment: I'm actually beginning to think that your struck-out first sentence is the most correct. There's a certain attraction to the 'preferred version' except that when I see the code again in a few months  it'll take me a few moments to figure out what it's doing unless I memorize the idiom (which I probably won't), while the more direct test takes no thought at all to see what's being checked. I'll have to think more about whether STATIC_ASSERT can help or if I should just decide that if someone changes the typedef, they need to be responsible for how that change might ripple.

Comment: The idiom I used might seem a bit odd at first, but it actually has lots of really nice applications. For instance if you're testing a value against a list of ranges, you can do it with 1 comparison/branch per range rather than 2. (I say a list because I assume with a single hard-coded range the compiler could make the equivalent optimization.) It's also very instructive for understanding unsigned arithmetic. As such it's an idiom I like to use and promote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's usually controlled by pragmas. For MSVC, you have [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and for GCC you have [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) (which admittedly don't allow for as fine-grained control over warnings as MSVC, but that's all you have).

Both allow for push/pop mechanics to only change the warnings for a few lines of code.

Comment: There's also the `_Pragma` (GCC) and `__pragma` (MSVC), which are functionally the same as `#pragma` but can be used in the definitions of macros.

Comment: `_Pragma` is actually C99, not gcc.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a pretty simple and straight forward solution. Copying the lower bound to a variable causes the compiler to stop complaining:

```
#define LOWER_BOUND 0
#define UPPER_BOUND 42

int is_value_in_range( some_typedef val)
{
    some_typedef lowerbound = LOWER_BOUND;

    return ((lowerbound <= val) && (val <= UPPER_BOUND));
}
```

I expect that in an optimized build, the compiler will still be able to easily get rid of the invariant comparison (I'll have to verify, though).

Comment: I suspect the warning will come back if/when the compiler's warning generation gets smarter.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than trying to silence the warning, why not do something about it and avoid the typedef in the first place? You can make overloads to handle specific cases and by avoiding the masking of warnings your more explicitly declaring that you're handling the cases you're dealing with. In my experience, that tends to force you to test new code instead of masking things which might happen in the future (like suddenly changing data types and then having to deal with values mysteriously failing to lie in expected ranges).

Comment: How do you do overloads in C?