# "Pointless comparison" warning in template with certain values

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-warnings

I have a templated (CUDA, although applies to C++) function (which I have simplified to make the point) as follows:

```
template<unsigned windowsize>
__global__ void someFunc()
{
    if (threadIdx.x < (32 - windowsize * 2))
    {
       // ... something exciting
    }
}
```

I'm using the code with "windowsize" set from 1-16. Compiling with nvcc within Visual Studio 2013, I get the following warning:

```
warning : pointless comparison of unsigned integer with zero
```

This is obviously for the case where windowsize=16 (for which the if statement evaluates to threadIdx.x < 0, i.e.  false) so the warning does make sense.

I've looked at the similar question: 
[How to silence a particular "pointless comparison of unsigned with zero" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259224/how-to-silence-a-particular-pointless-comparison-of-unsigned-with-zero-warning) but that is in a situation where a typedef is used rather than a template so the answers aren't suitable.

Is there a better way of constructing this function which will provide the same functionality without the warning? I could create separate functions which deal with windowsize more than and less than 16 differently, but in reality the function is more complex and I would feel like I'm unnecessarily duplicating and complicating code, which is the whole point in using the template to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious approach is to factor the comparison into a separate function:

```
template <unsigned WindowSize>
bool doSomethingExciting() { return threadIdx.x < (32u - WindowSize * 2u); }
template <>
bool doSomethingExciting<16>() { return false; }

template<unsigned windowsize>
__global__ void someFunc()
{
    if (doSomethingExciting<windowsize>())
    {
       // ... something exciting
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this does solve the problem, it's extra lines of code to do what the compiler is already doing for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try specializing the template function for 16:

```
template<unsigned windowsize>
__global__ void someFunc()
{
    //...
    std::cout << "called for windowsize " << windowsize << '\n';
}

template<>
__global__ void someFunc<16>()
{
    //...
    std::cout << "specialized for windowsize 16" << '\n';
}

void foo()
{
    someFunc<4>();
    someFunc<16>()
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/LXt8rA)

If there is common code, you can factor it out and create a separate function that both the regular and specialized version will call.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform two tests, where the first should be performed at compile time:

```
template<unsigned windowsize>
__global__ void someFunc()
{
    if (windowsize < 16)
    {
       if ((int)threadIdx.x < (int)(32 - windowsize * 2))
       {
          // ... something exciting
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a wrapper function which uses std::enable_if to check windowsize < 16 (couldn't get it to work with __global__ void), but the casting to int might be a nice solution.