# C comparison 'x < 0' where type of 'x' is arbitrary, i.e. might be unsigned

Tags: c, comparison, unsigned-integer, signedness

**GIVEN:**

A type defined as `TheValueT` that may be arbitrarily configured, e.g. as `uint8_t` or `int64_`. Let there be some code:

```
TheValueT   x = ...;

... do something to 'x' ...

if( x < 0 ) {
   /* Do something. */
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

It happens that if `TheValueT` is defined as an unsigned type, the compiler complains about 'condition always true because of limited range of type ...'.

**QUESTION:**

How can the compiler warning be avoided whilst letting `TheValueT` still be of arbitrary integer type? The solution should be applicable to the widest range of C compilers.

Comment: In parallel with `INT_MIN` implement `THEVALUET_MIN` and use `if ((THEVALUET_MIN < 0) && (x < 0)) /* ... */;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259224 is not exactly the same, but may give you some ideas.

Comment: @rtoijala: It does not.

Comment: You could try conditionalizing the code so that it is removed when you use an unsigned type for `TheValueT`, although that would entail adding a macro definition at the place where you define `TheValueT`.

Comment: Detail "It happens that if TheValueT is defined as an unsigned type" and the type is/as  narrower as `int`... the compiler complains

Comment: I'm not getting a warning anyway but does `if(TheValueT < TheValueT - TheValueT)` give you a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and safe way to write your test would be this:

```
TheValueT x = /* ... */;

if (x < 1 && x != 0) {
    // do something
}
```

It is possible that a clever enough compiler would warn about that anyway, but the same is true of any correct alternative that can be written to cover all possible integer types (including extension types).  That *does* work around the warning in my implementation.

No alternative requiring an arithmetic computation involving the value of `x` definedly produces the correct result in all cases -- these run into problems with values of `x` at the extremes of its or other types' ranges.

This does assume that `TheTypeT` must be an *integer* type.  If floating types are a possibility, too, then your best bet may be to just live with the warning, or to use a compiler flag to turn off that particular warning during production builds.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant, most comprising solution!

Comment: Since `x` can be "arbitrarily configured", what if `x` is a `double`, and has value `0.25`?.  It would pass your test (`x < 1 && x !=0`) and treat `0.25` as if it were a negative value.

Comment: Yes, @abelenky.  I address this issue in the last paragraph of the answer: the proffered solution explicitly addresses integer types only.

Comment: My answer handles floating-point types too. There is no need to just "live with the warning".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a *Generic* solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define less_than_zero(x) _Generic((x) + 0, \
  int: (x) < 0, \
  long: (x) < 0, \
  long long: (x) < 0, \
  default: (x) * 0 \
  )

#if 1
int main(void) {
  short sh = -1;
  int i = -1;
  long long ll = -1;
  unsigned short us = -1u;
  unsigned u = -1u;
  unsigned long long ull = -1u;

  if (less_than_zero(sh)) puts("sh");
  if (less_than_zero(i)) puts("i");
  if (less_than_zero(ll)) puts("ll");
  if (less_than_zero(us)) puts("us");
  if (less_than_zero(u)) puts("u");
  if (less_than_zero(ull)) puts("ull");
  return 0;
}
```

No *condition always true because of limited range of type* warning.
Output

```
sh
i
ll
```

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer If a compiler restriction exists, that should be part of the question.

Comment: Correct, I will add the note.

Comment: I like it, but it does not accommodate `TheTypeT` being a signed extension type.

Answer (score 1):

Variation on a [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger). Works for FP too.

```
if (x <= 0 && x != 0) {
```

Comment: Certainly, it has some charm to it. I could imagine, though, that constant value reduction of some compilers might be able to figure that out. John's solution with the 'x<1' contains a '-1' operation. Since for unsigned types the result is something void, constant reduction might be prevented from happening.